# OSX: Java 7 does not detects keyReleased

Tags: java, macos

Java 7 (1.7.0_21) seems not to recognize the keyReleased event inside Applets; I'm currently using OS X 10.7 (with latest updates) but I've experienced this behaviour also on 10.8. Java handles correctly the keyPressed and keyTyped events, but there seems to be no way to make it work with keyReleased.

I switched back to the Apple-provided Java 6, but I'd need to use Java 7. Any suggestions?

Comment: KeyListeners are notorious for having focus issues. Try key bindings instead

Comment: Does it work in Java 6? If it works there, you can report a bug on http://bugreport.sun.com/.